# How to set default avatar to user in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, avatar

I would like my users to have a default avatar. So I try this in a helper.

```
  def show_avatar(user)
    if File.exist?("/public/uploads/users/#{user.id}/avatar.jpg")
        image_tag ("accueil/profile_default.png"), class: 'rounded-circle', alt: "#{user.username}"
    else
      image_tag user.avatar_url, class: 'rounded-circle', alt: "#{user.username}"
    end
  end
```

But I don't understand why it doesn't work. I also tried with Dir.empty? but also without result.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`File.exist?("/public/uploads/users/#{user.id}/avatar.jpg")` will check the path from the root of your file system - not the root of your Rails app. Your logic is also backwards.

```
def show_avatar(user)
  if File.exist?(Rails.root.join("/public/uploads/users/#{user.id}/avatar.jpg"))
    image_tag user.avatar_url, class: 'rounded-circle', alt: user.username
  else
    image_tag "accueil/profile_default.png", class: 'rounded-circle', alt: user.username
   nd
end
```

Comment: It did the same to me. With this code it displays the profil_default image all the time

Comment: "It didn't work" is useless information. What exactly didn't work? Have you isolated any other factors that would cause it to fail? Does the file in fact exist?

Comment: I would like that if in the user's uploads folder it does not have an avatar.jpg that it be another image that is displayed but when I do what I said above it sends me back to each times the default avatar and not the user's avatar.

Comment: I do not understand why because it seems stupid. If the file /7/avatar.jpg exists, take that otherwise take another.

Comment: Yeah. But you have to remember here that I'm not looking at the entire code of your application or am in possession of a crystal ball that lets me magically see what you may have missed. You need to be able to do basic debugging and set up a test for this method if you are going to get anywhere.

Comment: If you are testing this by clicking around in a web browser there are tons of things that can go wrong. You want to write a helper test instead.